# Passing undefined parameter to function - check if variable exists

Tags: javascript

Consider the following Javascript:

```
function getType(obj){
    return(typeof(obj))
}
alert(typeof(obj))  //alerts "undefined" correctly
alert(getType(obj))   //throws an error: ReferenceError: obj is not defined
```

Why might this be happening? Is there any workaround? I am trying to write a function which checks if a variable exists.

Comment: Well, to just check if *something* with that name exists in the global context you can use `if (window["obj"])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is nothing to do with typeof.  The problem is that you cant pass undefined variables to functions.

```
function doNothing(obj){
}
doNothing(obj);
```

This code too results in the error:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined`
So it doesn't matter what code you write inside your function, as it won't be called.  The error happens before the function call.

`typeof` is an operator, not a function.
This is why it does not behave in the same way as functions.

Answer (score 4):

`typeof` is an operator, not a function, and therefore has powers that a function can't have.  There's no way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: and also, as an operator, does not require the braces around the operand.

Comment: Fair enough I suppose. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

Your function fails as soon as you try to pass an undefined object. You can't encapsulate the `typeof()` function. Well, you can, but it will always throw errors when passed undefined objects.