# require object from another file to be defined

Tags: javascript

I've lots of js file in a project and I would like to create a require function that would test if a file is already loaded. I'm aware of requirejs but I wish to do something small and easy. The problem with my function below is that it will throw an error `widgets is undefined` upon call of `requires`. How can I prevent that ?

```
function requires(obj, fn){
        if(typeof obj === 'undefined'){
            log('obj undefined');
            window.setTimeout(function(){requires(obj, fn)}, 10);
            //10 ms is arbitrary, i'm not a fan of that
        }else{
            fn();
        }
    }

//example using it  
requires(widgets, function(){
    window.widgets.showUserDlg = function showUserDlg(data) {
          ...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It goes to `else` condition and then `fn()` would run your callback in `widgets`. You need to get the `widgets` file first by AJAX?

Comment: You can **not** pass a undefined parameter to a function, it will always throw an error, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16942951/3880255), that's what you are doing, this will never work. You'll have to tweak your code depending on the enviorment you set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `widgets` is a global variable or an object property, you can pass it as a string name like

```
requires('widgets', function() { /* ... */ });
```

and then use `window` or that object as array to check it:

```
function requires(obj, fn){
    if(typeof window[obj] === 'undefined'){ // or container[obj]
        log('obj undefined');
        window.setTimeout(function(){requires(obj, fn)}, 10);
        //10 ms is arbitrary, i'm not a fan of that
    }else{
        fn();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ClemensHimmer I've added another possibility using objects

Comment: @ClemensHimmer deriving this to use namespace is easy. However I dislike dos and donts without something to back it up.So could you expand ? By the way widgets is the namespace, so there is that.

Comment: Indeed, i really had to downvote until Groover edited his answer. Not in global namespace? Besides you can just google that, the main reason is collision between scripts, you can just use your local scopes and everything is fine.

Comment: @ClemensHimmer I guess I didn't see his answer before the edit